# Bootstrap CSS or custom CSS is used?

Tags: css

I have a question, when you include bootstrap CSS and your custom CSS written by you in an HTML file, which one is used as the default or are both used? thanks!

Comment: No matter how many stylesheets you include, they are all used. But if you have styles for the same elements in multiple files, the order of the included files will determine which styles will be used. The n+1 order file styles will overwrite the n order file styles. Again, this is only about the styles that are for the same element.

Comment: @BeerusDev that’s highly inaccurate. Boostrap also changes the style of elements that don’t have a class like headlines and other elements. Besides that some of the classes that are used of bootstrap are relatively generic so calling them bootstrap class is misleading. And the own css is not the default one but is applied in combination with the bootstrap ones based on the cascade.

Answer (score 2):

Both will be used, but the CSS read last by the browser will take precedence over the other one. Usually Bootstrap is included first (by the developer), with a custom stylesheet included after that so that it's possible to override Bootstrap when needed.

Inline CSS (CSS in style tags inside of the `<body>` of the HTML code) always takes precedence over ANY stylesheet that is included in a `<link>` tag or a `<style>` tag in the header.

Comment: To add to @anatolhiman's correct answer, there are additional layers of specificity you may want to be familiar with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: thanks, I was wondering about this for quite some time but if so, how do you make both of them to be used at the same time?

Comment: You include your first css file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style1.css">` in `<head>` of your html document. Then add the exact same line below but edit the address so it points to style2.css. Now you have two different stylesheets being read by HTML. As long as there are no competing CSS classes/styles, both style1 and style2 will take full effect. But as mentioned above, specificity will decide how they impact the end result if both style1 and style2 contain overlapping styles. If two classes have the same specificity, the last one in the source order will overrule the first.